# How to correctly display the number of times a particular word has appeared in the user given input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am just starting python so I am working out exercises. I came across this one.

Question: Given a string of n words, help Alex to find out how many times his name appears in the string.

Constraint: 1 <= n <= 200

Sample input: Hi Alex WelcomeAlex Bye Alex.

Sample output : 3

My code for this:

```py
string =input("Enter input")
print(string.count(string))
```

But this is not giving required output.
How can I change this? Please help. Thanks.

Comment: You are counting `string` in `string`. Where did you instruct that you wanted the count of `'Alex'`? Maybe `string.count('Alex')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Austin is correct.

```
string =input("Enter input")
print(string.count('Alex'))
```

This should give you what you wanted.
Thank You